# hacking evolution where to find the freefall-OS

Tags: hacker-evolution-series

I have recently bought hacker evolution + dlc and gotten to the mission where you have to download and the freefall-OS, however no matter where I look I cannot find it. I have already downloaded and toyed with the multiboot.ini but cannot find the actual freefall-OS, googling freefall-OS and hacker evolution together gave no results.

Comment: which version of hacker evolution or just the original

Comment: this is in operation-electrosphere ep1 of the original hacker evolution. (By the way there is no tag for the original hacker-evolution game.

Comment: I know there isn't i just wanted it specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

freefall-os is the os in the room where the camera show.

```
scan freefall-os.azureblue.com
```

next you know what to do, good luck and good game mate

the only tricky part is to know the server of house apply to all is azureblue.com like the desktop-azureblue.com